# Find questions that I have answered and that have been closed

Tags: support, search, data-explorer

Is there a way I can search for questions that I have answered and that were later closed (for any reason)?

Looking at my list of answers (from my SO profile) isn't helpful as there is no visual indication whether the question is closed or not.

I am thinking this should be doable with SEDE but I am not familiar enough with the tool to write the query by myself. Could anyone help me achieve this? I have searched SEDE and meta but couldn't find any related query or question.

Comment: Ugh, I tried `user:me is:a closed:yes` in the on-site search. But that only brings up *questions* of mine which are closed. Not answers to questions that are closed. The `is:a` is ignored. To clarify for *me* it brings a self-answered question. But that's because it's the only question of mine which is closed. I tried it with MrUpsisidown's ID and it shows me questions of his without self-answers.

Comment: @VLAZ indeed, this returned 3 **questions** of mine that are closed.

Comment: Added clarification. Yes, it only ever searches for questions. Not even self-answers.

Comment: [Can closed:\[0-1\] apply to the parent question when is:answer is specified via search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104585) - feature request which is from a decade ago...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use SEDE to find your answers you can use this query, or click this [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1677457/2041737/) for a SEDE I've (just) created:

```sql
SELECT Q.Title,
       A.Id AS [Post Link]
FROM dbo.Posts A
     JOIN dbo.Posts Q ON A.ParentId = Q.Id
WHERE Q.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
  AND A.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##;
```

Note that this will not include deleted questions (or deleted answers). Though you *could* reference the `PostsWithDeleted` table, that won't help as user information is stripped from deleted content in that table; it contains very minimal information about the post.

Comment: Thank you. It would have been perfect if we could include deleted *questions* too but if that's not feasible, I am fine with this one. I think it's a good way to review my own list of answers that I most likely should not have placed.

Comment: You could still look at your [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/1238965) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1+is%3Aa), @MrUpsidown , though like mentioned in the comments on the question, you can't filter to those which are closed. (I wish the deleted posts pages accepted the [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/mine) parameter in the URL, rather than the need to hard code the user id.)

Comment: mine isn't supported anywhere, AFAIK. `current` on the other hand is widespread: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/current` (direct link for easy demonstration: https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/current)

Comment: Ahh, I must be misremembering the URL and getting it confused with the search feature, which uses `mine`, @ZoestandswithUkraine . I did https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/mine and that worked so put 2 and 2 together. Got to love "consistency". :)

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing. https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current works as well though, and only `current` works for the generic user page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/

Comment: It looks like, in truth, that the userid (or what would be there) part of the URL is just ignored, @ZoestandswithUkraine , as https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/ksdfjghsdklfjghskldfj takes me to my preferences too... /facepalm

Comment: Indeed, but https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/2029983 shows me your preferences (but I'm a mod, so I get special privileges). An invalid ID redirects to my own account though, so it appears to be some weird hybrid solution that presumably exists because mods occasionally need to edit profiles? /shrug